# Google Maps: Converting cid to new Google+ Local ID

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-plus

It seems that there's been a change in the Google Maps API. Google Places has now changed to Google+ Local. My question is an extension of this one here:

[Google places API: from CID to reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9333613/google-places-api-from-cid-to-reference)

His question was to store CIDs inside his database to be able to drop a single pin linking to the known place inside his map.

Example: http://maps.google.com/maps?cid=998657413562662319

It can be linked directly using the CID parameter, which will automatically drop the pin and link to the place.

In the past, clicking on the Places link on the map will bring you here:
Link: maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=998657413562662319

However, that has now changed. It will now link to Google+ instead:
Link: http://plus.google.com/100968423062387177527/about

(sorry, I'm limited to 2 hyperlinks)

My question is, how do you retrieve the CID now? What I intend to do is manually search the places beforehand using the normal Google Maps. I want to then retrieve the CID of these places and store it in my database manually. However, the CID is no longer available. What can I do?

Comment: Oh, I've found it. The CID can be retrieved from the Google+ Local page simply by clicking on the marker on the map.

Answer (score 6):

This answer is copying from the poster's comments following the original question, just to allow the question to be answered, because it looks like the user has not yet acquired sufficient reputation to self-answer a question. It's also here to make it clear to other StackOverflow users that the question has been addressed:

**The CID can be retrieved from the Google+ Local page simply by clicking on the marker on the map.**

Answer (score 0):

this is no longer the way to find a CID.

one option is to use this service:
https://cidfinder.view3.com/

you give them the google+ url and they will return the CID

another manual way to do it is clicking "view source" 
and searching for "CID"
you'll find something like this:
div role=button data-cid="18434216952359358766"

so the value of "data-cid" is the cid you're looking for.